# How to synchronize a personal online git repository with a shared one

Tags: git, github, fork

I'm new to Github, and I can't seem to do something that I think should be simple.

I have a personal remote repository, and a forked over a project into it. (Both from GitHub) From there I created a local copy using the clone, and I've been commiting and fetching from that repository.  Other people working on the same project have been commiting and fetching from a shared repository.

I would like to synchronize my remote repository from the shared one, so that I have the latest copy of the project from the shared repository in my personal one.  How do you do this?  I tried forking it again but that doesn't work.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer based on the GitHub help topic [Fork A Repo](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/).

First you need to set up a remote for the forked repository:

```
$ git remote add upstream git://github.com/PathToThe/ProjectYouForkedFrom.git
```

Then you need to pull in the upstream changes:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```

Comment: thanks. I'm using a tool called smartgit.  I don't know if those commands are in there, but I'll use the command line tool for now

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing what you typed. :) Are Gist or BlogTo related to the path of the forked project at all?

Comment: SmartGit (at least in version 2) has a menu called "Remote" with an option "Manage remotes" that you may find useful.